# Is there a way in web driver io that we can slow down and see drag and drop operation and where it is happening

Tags: webdriver-io

I am performing drag and drop operation and it is happening but I want to see where in the page drag and drop happened
Is there a way we can slow down the drag and drop and see where mouse is carrying our desired element